# smsManager.sendTextMessage not working for message that exceeds one sms character limit

Tags: android, android-studio, sms, smsmanager

I am working with a project which sends firebase dynamic link invitation to friends via sms. My code runs perfecly fine and sends sms  when I send smaller links as invitation. like

```
    try {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, "Check It Out. This one is very nice and useful https://v5uht.app.goo.gl/Zi7X", null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cheers :D :D", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But it doesn't send sms when I include bigger link which exceeds one sms character limit though it shows the toast notification.

```
    String myNewLink = "https://v5uht.app.goo.gl/?link=http://expensecount.com/&apn=com.chtl.ribath.fdynamic1&amv=1&afl=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id%3Dcom.belief.colorgalaxy&myPage=2";
    try {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, myNewLink, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cheers :D :D", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

what shall I do to include the whole link which is in myNewLink and make it working. Thank you.

Comment: You must send it in parts.Tell me if you need any code :)

Comment: i searched for some example but got nothing... if you plz share some code it would be hugely helpful :D @MohammadZ

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This code might help you:

```
try {

    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    ArrayList<String> msgArray = smsManager.divideMessage(msg);

    smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNo, null,msgArray, null, null);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I was trying to send SMS using sendTextMessage of SmsManager class with all permissions enabled on Android Nougat (Nexus). SMS were not sent. Just copied this code. It works perfectly now. Hope this helps others :)

Comment: @varun Glad to hear that... :)

Comment: great answer and great question! It was out of my mind the problem on too long message. Thanks guys!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that :)